# C++ Unable to Perform Flow Control Based on STL Container's Type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, stl

The following is an example of a class that iterates through an STL container and prints out each element, with the initialization code attached for the main().

It seems as if the compiler parses the entire ContainerPrinterClass at compile time and throws an error when it gets to a line that is unsupported by an element in one of the passed in STL containers, for example `element.first/element.second` for type `int` in the vector. Yet, it's not supposed to be even entering that condition because flow control clearly states to only enter it `if (std::is_same<T, std::map<int, std::string>>::value)` is true.

The opposite is also true for when the map is passed into the print function and the compiler flags the error in the `else` condition where it tries to print the element, which is a std::pair and can't. But it should not even be in that else condition, since if a map is passed it, execution goes to the `if` condition and skips the `else` entirely.

I've also attempted with trying to substitute the `(typeid(*container) == typeid(std::map<int, std::string>))` and `dynamic_cast` to check if the element is a `std::pair` with same results, where the compiler parses all the conditions in the printer function (even the incorrect ones for a particular type) at compile time.

So does anyone know how to provide this kind of template/generic functionality akin to Java's `instanceOf` and not have the compiler go blindly parsing the code in the conditions it's not supposed to go into for that particular type?

---

```
// the printer class
class ContainterPrinterClass {
public:
ContainterPrinterClass() {};

template<class T> void printElementsInContainer(T *container) {
    // if container type is map, print key and value
    if (std::is_same<T, std::map<int, std::string>>::value) {
        for each (auto element in *container) {
            std::cout << "key: " << element.first << " val: " << element.second << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        // else if container is a vector, print just element
        for each (auto element in *container) {
            std::cout << "val: " << element << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
};
```

---

```
// in main()
ContainterPrinterClass containerPrinterClass;

std::vector<int> vectorOfInts = {1};
containerPrinterClass.printElementsInContainer<std::vector<int>>(&vectorOfInts);

std::map<int, std::string> mapOfStrings = {std::pair<int, std::string>(2, "Two")};
containerPrinterClass.printElementsInContainer<std::map<int, std::string>>(&mapOfStrings);
```

---

This however it will not compile and is giving the following error:

```
1>e:\workbench\projects\visualstudio_workspaces\tuts\testbed1\basic_app\basic_app.cpp(503): error C2228: left of '.first' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'
1>          e:\workbench\projects\visualstudio_workspaces\tuts\testbed1\basic_app\basic_app.cpp(747) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void ContainterPrinterClass::printElementsInContainer<std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>>(T *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>  ,            T=std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>
1>          ]
1>e:\workbench\projects\visualstudio_workspaces\tuts\testbed1\basic_app\basic_app.cpp(503): error C2228: left of '.second' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'
1>e:\workbench\projects\visualstudio_workspaces\tuts\testbed1\basic_app\basic_app.cpp(508): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(498): could be 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(478): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(458): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(438): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(double)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(418): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(float)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(397): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(377): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(__int64)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(356): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(336): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(long)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(316): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(291): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(int)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(271): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(237): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(short)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(217): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(210): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(203): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(197): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(699): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(746): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(784): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(831): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(957): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const signed char *)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(964): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(971): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const unsigned char *)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(978): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char)'
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(988): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &&,const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\visualstudio2013pro\vc\include\ostream(1026): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const std::error_code &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          e:\workbench\projects\visualstudio_workspaces\tuts\testbed1\basic_app\basic_app.cpp(750) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void ContainterPrinterClass::printElementsInContainer<std::map<int,std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>(T *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::string
1>  ,            T=std::map<int,std::string,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,std::string>>>
1>          ]
```

Comment: Why not just provide a specialization of `printElementsInContainer` for `std::map<int, std::string>`?

Comment: Note that `for each` is a Visual C++ extension to C++ and is not standard. If you are looking for the C++11 container iteration loop structure, it is `for (auto & element : *container)`. (But why aren't you passing your container by reference?)

Comment: When compiling, all code paths must contain valid code, so trying to access the members `first` and `second` is not going to compile when the function template is specialized for `std::vector`. You can tag dispatch based on `true_type/false_type` that `std::is_same` yields to implementations that handle the `map` and `vector` cases separately. Easiest solution is to use the [pretty printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)

Comment: `if` is not a conditional code compilation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function template is instantiated all of its code need to be correct code. When you want to execute code which depends on capabilities of the template parameters you need to dispatch to suitable function template taking advantage of the respect abilities. For example, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::map<int, std::string>>::value>::type
printElementsInContainer(T *container) {
    for (auto&& element: *container) {
        std::cout << "key: " << element.first << " val: " << element.second << '\n';
    }
}
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, std::map<int, std::string>>::value>::type
printElementsInContainer(T *container) {
    for (auto&& element: *container) {
        std::cout << "val: " << element << '\n';
    }
}
```

To some extend, the use of `std::enable_if<...>` does the corresponding type conditional.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys, they're all valid options, however I must choose Dietmar's answer as the best as his answer points to std::enable which gives me exactly what I'm looking for aka "This is useful to hide signatures on compile time when a particular condition is not met" as it says in the documentation!

Comment: @sharik: I think something like C++ has much to learn wherever you stand: I'm programming C++ since nearly 25 years and right now I'm sitting in a session at the C++ committee meeting - ... and I'm still learning! (today's major lesson for me was from the [`std::void_t<...>` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3911.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

This fails because even though `std::is_same` is going to return the same value for any one particular `T`, the other branch of the conditional still needs to be compiled.

This means that when you call with `std::vector<int>`, even though the `std::is_same` expression evaluates to false, the `if` body still needs to be correct, and `int` doesn't have a `first` member.

The same applies in the map case; the `else` body still needs to compile, and it doesn't because there isn't an `operator<<` that accepts `std::pair<const int, std::string>`.

Either use overloads, template specialization, or SFINAE to activate only the correct code.  Here is an example using specialization:

```
template<class T> void printElementsInContainer(T *container) {
    for each (auto element in *container) {
        std::cout << "val: " << element << std::endl;
    }
}

template<> void printElementsInContainer(std::map<int, std::string> *container) {
    for each (auto element in *container) {
        std::cout << "key: " << element.first << " val: " << element.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I would instead consider combining overloading with your main function; you can separate the logic of iterating (which is the same for all containers) from the logic of displaying elements (which depends on the type of element in each container).

This code will work with any `std::map` (as long as the key and value can be written to a stream), and also `std::multimap`, `std::unordered_map`, or in general any standard (or custom) container whose elements are `std::pair`.  It will also work with any container whose elements are not pairs but can be written to streams, such as your `std::vector<int>`.

```
template<class TStream, class TElement>
void writeElementTo(TStream & stream, TElement const & element)
{
    stream << "val: " << element;
}

template<class TStream, class TKey, class TValue>
void writeElementTo(TStream & stream, std::pair<TKey, TValue> const & element)
{
    stream << "key: " element.first << "value: " << element.second;
}

template<class T> void printElementsInContainer(T *container) {
    for each (auto element in *container) {
        writeElementTo(std::cout, element);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```